# jQuery make element size persist definitively

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

So I have two tables (A and B), and the idea is to be able to drag a few elements from cells in table A into cells in table B.

The cells are all irregularly sized (different colspans), and currently, the draggable elements within the cells take up 100% of the parent container (when the page loads). Now what I want is for the elements widths to NOT change upon being placed within another cell in table B. What happens now is that the element will grow or shrink to fit the new parent element.

I've tried doing something like `$(this).width($(this).width())` to get the definite width in pixels and apply that (as opposed to this implied 100%), and that sort of works, except that it for some reason stretches the container cell.

If you need to visualize whats happening, here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JordanForeman/Fdew3/12/)

In regards to the fiddle, table A is actually the second table and table B is the first. Sorry if that throws anyone off.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting

```
.outerWidth()
```

http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the `colspan` which you have given in Table A cells. Remove the `colspan` and give a specific width it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use table for each row and make table drag-gable